# emu8086 Procedure as input and outputs the interrupt

Tags: assembly, x86-16

emu8086 Procedure as input and outputs the interrupt.
The program calculates the arithmetic mean.
It would be desirable to increase the speed of the program.
Why working with program procedures is significantly slower?

```
include 'emu8086.inc'


;srednee arifmiticheskoe
data segment  
    msg1 db '4islo ne vhodit v diapazon ot 1 do 30, povtorite vvod.'
    mas dw 30 DUP(?)
    razmernost dw ?
    s dw ?
    n dw ?

ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax





xor ax, ax
xor si, si
xor cx,cx

vvod1:CALL   pthis
     DB  'The dimension of the array(ot 1 do 30):', 0
     call SCAN_NUM;zapros vvoda razmernost
     cmp cx,30
     JG OSHIBKA 
     cmp cx,0
     JNL  razm
    oshibka:   lea si,msg1
       call print_string
       call clear_screen
       jmp vvod1 
  razm:   mov razmernost,cx;pomes4enie x v peremennyiy x  


     xor si,si
     mov ax,0     

     vvod2:push cx 
     CALL   pthis
     Db  13, 10, 'ввод элемента массива number ', 0 
     CALL   print_num 
     Print ' : '
     call SCAN_NUM           
     mov mas[si], cx        
     add si, 2
     inc ax
     pop cx
     loop vvod2
     call clear_screen

xor ax, ax
xor si, si
mov cx, razmernost
@1:
add ax, mas[si]
add si, 2
inc n
loop @1
cwd
idiv n
mov s, ax


PRINT 'MAS = '
xor si, si 
mov cx, razmernost
@22:
xor ax, ax
add ax, mas[si]
add si, 2  
CALL   print_num  
Print ' '
loop @22 
gotoxy 0,1
PRINT 'average = ' 
Print ' '
mov ax, s
CALL   print_num 


DEFINE_SCAN_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_STRING
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS  
DEFINE_PTHIS
DEFINE_clear_screen


    konec: mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h    
ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

Comment: Slower than what? Where in your code have you found the bottleneck(s) to be? By the way, why are there strings embedded in your code? Does `pthis` override its return address?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, I just ran it (actually, it's fast). First of all, EMU8086 has a speed control, next image shows where :

[image]

On the other hand, you are probably running the program inside the EMU8086. Don't. Find the executable of your program and run it, next image shows where it is:

[image]

Your executable will have a name like "my_program.exe_" (pay attention to the underscore at the end). Rename it to "my_program.exe", and run it in a DOS box or virtual machine, you will see how fast your program is when not running inside EMU8086.

Finally, we can blame your computer. Are you using your grandma's computer?

Comment: thank you very much for your help but I'm probably not correctly put it once you got it wrong.
I mean how to convert my command procedures interrupt

Comment: I don't understand : "how to convert my command procedures interrupt"?

Comment: command procedures interrupt command
so to speak the same way solutions

Comment: Maybe you should avoid using "emu8086.inc" and create your own procedures.

Comment: Your removed comment was correct (lea, ah 9, int 21 = print).

Comment: pkey db "press any key...$" 
...........................................
   lea dx, pkey
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h        ; output string at ds:dx
............................................

include 'emu8086.inc'
PRINT 'press any key...$' 

.............................................

Comment: That I wanted to show that it is necessary to replace a similar manner
input and output

Comment: The output is easy: just 3 lines (lea, ah 9, int 21). The input is not easy : you have to capture the string, then use a procedure to convert it from string to int.